# Count the same elements with insensitive case in a list in python

Tags: python, list, count, case-insensitive

I am new to python and I have a question related to counting elements in a list in the insensitive case. For example I have a list as below:

```
My_list = ['modulus of elasticity', 'NIRS', 'mechanical properties', 'Modulus of elasticity', 'NIRS', 'mechanical properties']
```

My desired dictionary should be sth like this:

```
Desired_dictionary = {'modulus of elasticity': 2, 'NIRS': 2, 'mechanical properties': 2}
```

Actually I know how to count them in a normal way but the word like: **modulus of elasticity** and **Modulus of elasticity** will count as the different elements. Noted that: I want to keep **NIRS** to remain in capital letters. I wonder if there is a way to handle with this sensitive case in python. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `.lower()` method on string and then compare them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

orig = Counter(My_list)
lower = Counter(map(str.lower, My_list))

desired = {}
for k_orig in orig:
     k_lower = k_orig.lower()
     if lower[k_lower] == orig[k_orig]:
         desired[k_orig] = orig[k_orig]
     else:
         desired[k_lower] = lower[k_lower]

desired
# {'modulus of elasticity': 2, 'NIRS': 2, 'mechanical properties': 2}
```

Comment: it is not really what I want: I want to keep **NIRS** as the capital letters without changing.

Comment: What's the logic behind that? If an element only occurs in a single form, keep it?

Comment: **NIRS** in my case it is just the abbreviation of a word so I just want to keep it in capital letters.

Comment: Well, obviously, no code can know that. So you would have to give helpers some generally applicable logic which elements are case sensitive and which aren't.

Comment: So there is no way to compare them independently without getting effect of the other elements in a list?

Comment: You could do separate counts for originals and lower cased elements and keep the originals if the counts are the same and the lower cased ones if the counts differ.

Comment: I am thinking of this too. Can you edit your answer then?

Comment: @schwobaseggl-- Thanks that is what I want :)